# wordpress docker

Tags: wordpress, docker

В офф конфиге докера по вордпрессу есть вот такой пункт:

```
RUN set -ex; \
    curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fSL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-${WORDPRESS_VERSION}.tar.gz"; \
    echo "$WORDPRESS_SHA1 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
# upstream tarballs include ./wordpress/ so this gives us /usr/src/wordpress
    tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C /usr/src/; \
    rm wordpress.tar.gz; \
    chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/src/wordpress
```

Может мне кто нибудь объяснить, зачем он качает вордпресс в ту папку? Для чего это вообще?

Comment: Ставит нужную версию wordpress и распаковывает ее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> зачем он качает вордпресс в ту папку?

согласно [fhs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FHS) каталог `/usr/src` — вполне подходящее место для расположения тех исходных текстов, которые используются «[for reference purpose](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s12.html#purpose30)» («чтобы на них ссылаться»). собственно, именно так содержимое `/usr/src/wordpress` в дальнейшем и используется (см. далее).

> Для чего это вообще?

при запуске контейнера из этого образа выполняется [скрипт](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh), указанный как «точка входа»:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

при первом запуске скрипт [не обнаружит](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L48) в текущем каталоге файла `index.php`:

```
if [ ! -e index.php ] && [ ! -e wp-includes/version.php ]; then
```

и [скопирует](https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh#L72) содержимое каталога `/usr/src/wordpress` в текущий:

```
tar "${sourceTarArgs[@]}" . | tar "${targetTarArgs[@]}"
```

вот это скопированное содержимое уже и будет использоваться http-сервером (также установленном внутри образа) для отображения сайта. это именно та цель, для которой образ и создаётся.

зачем нужно копирование? в частности для того, чтобы текущий каталог можно было примонтировать из хост-системы внутрь образа и при первом же запуске контейнера получить в этом каталоге работоспособный docroot сайта, который будет сохраняться и после пересоздания контейнера.